# the function strcmp in c doesn't detect the symbol >?

Tags: c, string

So, I just want to detect the symbol '>' in a the list of arguments stored in args, so I use strcmp() but the execution returns me a  segmentation error (core dumped). I also tried comparing the the first character with its ascii value but it didn't work either. Is there another way for me to recognize the > symbol in a string ?

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], ">") == 0){

if(execlp("date", "date", NULL) == -1){
    perror("erreur exec");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Segmentation faults are best tracked down with the help of a debugger. Have you tried that? A (likely) related question: what does `argv[1]` do if `argv` has only one element?

Comment: First of all you should check `argc`. Second - `>` is a special character interpreted by the shell, and cannot be passed as is. It needs to be escaped or quoted.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, so I did try with ">" and '>' but I think it doesn't consider it the same as > because the if condition wasn't entered, For the second anwser, there IS a segmentation error when i don't give any argument to the program but I think it's just an error cause I'm calling argv[1] in the program

Comment: Your segfault is because when you call it without parameters, there's no `argv[1]`, it stops at `argv[0]` which is probably the program name or perhaps the program name and path. You should check `argc` first, and bail early (perhaps with a message that says your program expects an argument), or skip the code that accesses `argv[1]`.

Comment: I suggest you temporarily alter your program to simply print the value in `argc` and then loop over all `argv[n]` printing each argument so you can see how the system passes command line parameters to the program. Only then a true Jedi you will become.

Comment: I tried printing each argument and I encountered two cases: 
1- when I give > with another argument like a file name, it only prints me argv[0] which is the program name.
2- when I give > alone , I have a syntax error from the bash

Answer (score 0):

Compiling and linking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        if (strcmp(argv[i], ">") == 0)
            printf("Argument %d is \">\".\n", i);
}
```

into an example named `demo` with Apple Clang 11.0 on macOS 10.14.6 and executing the command:

```
./demo ">"
```

with, for example, csh, results in output:

```
Argument 1 is ">".
```

In contrast, executing:

```
./demo > foo
```

results in no output in the terminal or in `foo` because the shell parses `>` and `foo` and omits them from the arguments it passes to the program.

Comment: thanks, so there isn't a way where it can detect > alone ? cause as I said it, I'm making a shell and it has to recognise the > for a redirection